# EXCEL - How to use VLOOKUP to get the entire table contents?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007, vlookup

I have an Excel sheet with columns:

*Screenshot*

[image: Excel Screenshot]

*Data*

```
Table 1                                                                                                                 Table 2 
METADATA    Date    ENTERPRISE     PersonNumber AssignmentNumber    EntryDate   EffectiveStartDate  EffectiveEndDate    Period of service id            Person number   period of service id 
MERGE       Date    ENTERPRISE      1505881                 E151                2019/08/05  2019/08/05            4712/12/31                                        1505881         231
MERGE       Date    ENTERPRISE      1505882                 E152                2019/08/05  2019/08/05             4712/12/31                                       1505882         232
```

I want to match the columns `Person number` in both tables and return the period of service against the Table 2 for each matched person number in Table 1.

How can I use VLOOKUP for this ??

Comment: Edit the question and show each table content separately.

Comment: Your narrative hasn't been edited yet your sample data still lacks a Table 1 data matrix. Please provide one.

Comment: Please [Edit] your post & upload sample data in proper format, help us to fix the issue !!

Comment: Hi I have inserted an image .... does that help to understand the question ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Combination of `INDEX` & `SMALL` wrapped with `IFERROR`, solves the issue.*

[image]

- An array formula in cell `A61`:

  ```
  =IFERROR(INDEX($B$57:$B$59, SMALL(IF(COUNTIF($A57, $D$50:$D$52), ROW($B$57:$B$59)-MIN(ROW($B$57:$B$59))+1), ROW(A$1)), COLUMN(A$1)),"No Match")
  ```
- Finish formula with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter** & fill down.

*Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.*

Comment: Glad to help you @Sree ,, keep asking ☺